# Weight Paint strange splotches

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, mirror, rigify

I am trying to weight paint my model however i keep getting weird splotches all over my model that look like this:

[image]

And cause posing errors like this: [image]

When I paint out the splotches, other splotches appear when I select other bones. I have Auto Normalize and X-Mirror turned on like the tutorial i'm following told me to.

[image]

Why is this happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The file is located here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wpkN-A2ze-snSMdZaGFut86E3KlOfTxa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: remove these vertices from all groups and repaint them in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: I thought of trying that, I just wasn't sure if it would mess anything up.

Comment: no reason, select this part in Edit mode, then in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, in the dropdown menu on the right of the vertex group list, choose Remove From All Groups, then select the armature, shift select the mash, switch to Weight Paint mode, select the good bone and paint

Comment: @moonboots your method is working but it seems like i will have to go through every bone in the armature which would be very time consuming. Is there a way to increase the speed of my workflow?

Comment: no you don't have to go through every bone if you select this part of the mesh and click on Remove From All Groups  ;)  Then you just need to select the bone that influence this part and paint